# GoogleSignInClient.signOut() for Android does not sign out user

Tags: java, android, google-api

1) In my **HomeActivity** screen there will be a button for user sign out. This button leads to **signOut()** method of **LoginActivity**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    //adding an onclicklistener to signOut button
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LoginActivity loginActivity = new LoginActivity();
            loginActivity.signOut();
        }
    });
}
```

2) In my **LoginActivity**, the **signOut()** method will perfom what is in [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect) provided by Google

```
public void signOut() {
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disconnecting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
}
```

I was hoping the code above would work but what happens is that when the intent to go back to LoginActivity is executed after sign out, the onStart() method below goes into *if (account != null)* and returns the user that was supposed to be logged out

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Check for existing Google Sign In account
    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

    if (account != null) {
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Logged as" + account.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect() api will clear previously login account details.  Try using below snippet in your signout onComplete() method in  listener.

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)) {
        mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(context);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the method that you said is from the deprecated GoogleApiClient, I'm using GoogleSignInClient so didn't work